# Trying to upgrade from 12.04 LTS x64 to 12.10 but it does not appear

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade from 12.04 LTS x64 to 12.10 but it does not appear following directions on the ubuntu.com website.  Kindly point in right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

youр config file must be set up to let you upgrade distros releases.

```
cd /etc/update-manager/
gksudo gedit release-upgrades
```

make sure that the end line looks like this :

```
Prompt=normal
```